# Why does the series with terms $\frac{\log n}{n^2 - n}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms

So Wolfram tells me that the series:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\log{n}}{n^2 -n}$$
converges and it says that this can be shown by the comparison test. What series is sufficient to show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\log n<\sqrt{n}$, so your terms are smaller than $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2-n}$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, that's the inequality I need. Thanks\

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\log(n) < \sqrt{n} = n^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$
Thus
$$ \frac{\log(n)}{n^2-n}
 < \frac{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}{n^2-n}. $$
Can you finish it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because $\ln{n}<\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}$ for all $n>1$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n\geq2$, we have $n^{2}-n\geq\frac{n^{2}}{2}$, so $\frac{\ln n}{n^{2}-n}\leq\frac{\ln n}{\frac{1}{2}n^{2}}$.
Moreover, for any $x\geq4$, $\ln x<\sqrt{x}$. Therefore 
$$
\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^{2}-n}\leq2\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^{2}}\leq2\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}<\infty,
$$ where the last infinite series is convergent by integral test.

Answer (score 1):

You may notice that $\frac{\log(n)}{n^2-n}=\log(n)\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is positive for any $n\geq 2$, but bounded by $\frac{\log n}{n-1}-\frac{\log(n+1)}{n}+\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}$ which is a telescopic term. In particular
$$ 0\leq \sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{\log n}{n^2-n} \leq\sum_{n=2}^{N}\left(\frac{\log n}{n-1}-\frac{\log(n+1)}{n}+\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right) \leq 1+\log 2$$
and the given series is absolutely convergent. You may also prove that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{H_n}{n^2-n}=2,\quad \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\gamma}{n^2-n}=\gamma,\qquad \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{2(n^3-n^2)}=1-\frac{\pi^2}{12} $$
to get that the value of the original series is pretty close to $\color{blue}{1-\gamma+\tfrac{\pi^2}{12}\approx\frac{5}{4}}$.
Additionally, it has the following nice integral representation:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\log n}{n^2-n}&=&\int_{0}^{z}\frac{z\log z}{(1-z)\log(1-z)}\,dz=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n}\\&=&\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}\zeta(m+1)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{H_x}{x}\,dx. \end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can compare with a *Bertrand's series*. Actually the general term is *equivalent* to the general term of the Bertrand's series$\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^2\log n}$.

Now a Bertrand's series $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^\alpha\log^\beta n}$ is known to converge if and only if

- $\alpha>1$ or
- $\alpha=1$ and $\beta>1$.

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler. For any $n\ge 2$ we have

$ \dfrac{\log{n}}{n^2 -n}\le\dfrac{2\log{n}}{n^2}\quad(*)$

furthermore we can confront with the integral

$\int_2^{m} \frac{2\log x}{x^2} \, dx=2\left[-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{\log n}{n}\right]_2^m=2\left(-\frac{1}{m}-\frac{\log m}{m}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\log 2}{2}\right)\to 1+\log 2$ as $m\to+\infty$

As the integral converges the RHS of $(*)$ converges and thus the given series converges as well

Hope this helps